# I can't fix Runtime Errorr

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, runtime-error

Please I need help, I keep having this error message when I run my codes.

**RuntimeError: Attempting to capture an EagerTensor without building a function**.

I have a very little knowledge of programming and machine learning. Any help will be very much appreciated.

```
y=tf.convert_to_tensor(y)#convert pd.dataframe to tensorflow
```

The issue started when I ran the above code to convert from pandas dataframe to tensorflow since the former was also giving error message.

**I can put the entire codes here if required**

**This is the error message I got**

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-4411ee976a0d> in <module>
      8     cost = sess.run(cost_function, feed_dict={x: X_train, y_: y_train})
      9     cost_history = np.append(cost_history, cost)
---> 10     correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
     11     accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
     12     # print("Accuracy: ", (sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: test_x, y_: test_y})))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\deprecation.py in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
    505                 'in a future version' if date is None else ('after %s' % date),
    506                 instructions)
--> 507       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    508 
    509     doc = _add_deprecated_arg_notice_to_docstring(

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\math_ops.py in argmax(input, axis, name, dimension, output_type)
    139   axis = deprecation.deprecated_argument_lookup("axis", axis, "dimension",
    140                                                 dimension)
--> 141   return argmax_v2(input, axis, output_type, name)
    142 
    143 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\math_ops.py in argmax_v2(input, axis, output_type, name)
    185   if axis is None:
    186     axis = 0
--> 187   return gen_math_ops.arg_max(input, axis, name=name, output_type=output_type)
    188 
    189 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py in arg_max(input, dimension, output_type, name)
    846   _, _, _op, _outputs = _op_def_library._apply_op_helper(
    847         "ArgMax", input=input, dimension=dimension, output_type=output_type,
--> 848                   name=name)
    849   _result = _outputs[:]
    850   if _execute.must_record_gradient():

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    466               dtype=dtype,
    467               as_ref=input_arg.is_ref,
--> 468               preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
    469         except TypeError as err:
    470           if dtype is None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, dtype_hint, ctx, accepted_result_types)
   1278       graph = get_default_graph()
   1279       if not graph.building_function:
-> 1280         raise RuntimeError("Attempting to capture an EagerTensor without "
   1281                            "building a function.")
   1282       return graph.capture(value, name=name)

RuntimeError: Attempting to capture an EagerTensor without building a function.
```

Answer (score 0):

`tf.convert_to_tensor` cannot convert Pandas dataframes to Tensors. To load data from a Pandas dataframe into TensorFlow, consult the following guide:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/pandas_dataframe